# Magento loop inside another loop sub categories with products of that sub category inside

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to build a block in Magento (1.8 comunity edition)

In this block I want to seperate the sub categories

lets say that the parent is Power tools

and it has 3 sub categories

saws
routers
drills

so the outcome would be something like this...

Power tools
  saws
  routers
  drills

I have the parent category set to display a block, and my existing code will show the sub categories just fine. I get the sub categories output along with their wrapping divs along with the links pointing to the corret subcategory page, but the product lists inside... no joy!

So far I have this for code...

```
<?php

$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>




<div class="" style="width: 90%; float:right;margin-right: 5%;">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12" style="border: 2px dotted #3t6; font-size: 2em; margin:1em 0;">

        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" /></a>


    </div>



    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:200px; border: 1px solid #333;">


        <h1>test this</h1>
        <?php
        $parent_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
        $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        ?>

        <?php echo $parent_cat->getid() ; ?>//this shows the correct id

        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>// start individual products for the sub category
        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
               <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></


        <?php endforeach; ?>// end product loop for the individual products

    </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

So I thought the the $this-> might be referencing the previous call for the outside loop (Not sure though if that makes sense) so I tried something like this...

```
        <?php
        $parent_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
        $_productCollection = $parent_cat->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        ?>
```

no errors but still no joy.

I am new to loops in Magento so I am totally flailing here, would like it if someone could set me straight on what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So digging around I found some stuff that worked for me, still not sure if this is the best way to do it, but for a novice it seems to work well.

much thans to Adam Moss for his answer on another post on stack

[Magento Product Listing by Category ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748730/magento-product-listing-by-category-id)

The only  thing that I did was use the $category-getId(); to pull in the proper Cat id so that the sub category pulled the proper product collection!!! AWESOME!

```
<?php

        $categoryid = $category->getId();

        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->load($categoryid);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

<?php 
     // do stuff here, like...
      echo $_product->getShortDescription(); 
?>

<?php } ?>
```